# Animate every table row once using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to animate every table row once using jquery jusgt like the flashing effect to every row once in a single go. I have tried below code but
no positive result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var rowsCount = 0;
    var blinking_rows = [];
    $('#tblOne tbody tr').each(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        left: '250px',
        opacity: '0.5',
        height: '150px',
        width: '150px'
      });
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    var rowsCount = 0;
    var blinking_rows = [];
    $('#tblOne tbody tr').each(function(){
     $(this).animate({
     left: '250px',
        opacity: '0.5',
     height: '150px',
     width: '150px'
  });
 });
   },5000);
  });

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample animation. Every time the function in `setInterval` is called, one row in the table is animated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rowsCount = 0;
  var lenTable = 3;
  setInterval(function() {    
    $('#tblOne tbody tr').not(':eq(rowsCount)').animate({
      opacity: '1',
      fontSize: "12px",
    });
    $('#tblOne tbody tr').eq(rowsCount).animate({
      opacity: '0.5',
      fontSize: "48px",
    });
    rowsCount = (rowsCount + 1) % lenTable;
    console.log(rowsCount);
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tblOne" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
    <td>&#9632;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tblOne tbody').each(function(){...})
```

What about that? Before you were "eaching" on **tbody tr** not on **tbody**. I dont think tr had any tr children in your code.

I hope I'm right !

Comment: You are right. but my logic is in one go first row animates then after some delay second row animates and so on.

Comment: Ah ok so everything within a row should animate ...now I get it